# Function that returns the year/s with most release albums

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

Following is a list of Beatles album releases with years. Write a function that returns the year/s
with most album releases. If there is one year, return a string, else return an array.

```
var beatles_discography = {
 "Please Please Me": 1963,
 "With the Beatles": 1963,
 "A Hard Day's Night ": 1964, 
 "Beatles for Sale ": 1964, 
 "Twist and Shout ": 1964, 
 "Help ": 1965, 
 "Rubber Soul ": 1965,
 "Revolver": 1966,
 "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band": 1967,
 "Magical Mystery Tour ": 1967, 
 "The Beatles ": 1968, 
 "Yellow Submarine ": 1969 ,
 "Abbey Road": 1969, 
 "Let It Be ": 1970
}
```

I tried to like this So far:-

```
var x = {
 "Please Please Me": 1963,
 "With the Beatles": 1963,
 "A Hard Day's Night ": 1964, 
 "Beatles for Sale ": 1964, 
 "Twist and Shout ": 1964, 
 "Help ": 1965, 
 "Rubber Soul ": 1965,
 "Revolver": 1966,
 "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band": 1967,
 "Magical Mystery Tour ": 1967, 
 "The Beatles ": 1968, 
 "Yellow Submarine ": 1969 ,
 "Abbey Road": 1969, 
 "Let It Be ": 1970
}
var y = {};

for (var key in x){
  y[x[key]] = y[x[key]] ? y[x[key]] + 1: 1;
}
var arr = Object.keys(y);
function getYear(arr){
  for (var m=0; m<arr.length -1; m++){
  if(y[arr[0]] > y[arr[1]]){
    return arr[0];
  }else{
    var temp = [];
    if(y[m] == y[m+1]){
      temp.push(arr[m],arr[m+1]);
    }
    return temp;
  }
  }
}

console.log(getYear(arr));
```

my expected output for this code is 1964, because in the list I have only this year repeated 3 times. If in the object I have 1965 also 3 times then I need to return an array like [1964, 1965]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: can you please share what you have tried so far; so that people can make suggestions for you instead of asking a very homework like question?

Comment: @feanor07 updated the code in the question

Comment: Post doubts and blockers here, not your assignments

Comment: @Anji add your expected output to the question.

Comment: @Justcode my expected output for this code is 1964, because in the list I have only this year repeated 3 times. If in the object I have 1965 also 3 times then I need to return an array like [1964, 1965]

Comment: @DineshK This is not my assignment. I am trying improve my coding skills by solving these kind of problems.

Comment: but so your point is to get the year with the most of albums?

Answer (score 2):

```
var albums = {
    "Please Please Me": 1963,
    "With the Beatles": 1963,
    "A Hard Day's Night ": 1964,
    "Beatles for Sale ": 1964,
    "Twist and Shout ": 1964,
    "Help ": 1963,
    "Rubber Soul ": 1965,
    "Revolver": 1966,
    "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band": 1967,
    "Magical Mystery Tour ": 1967,
    "The Beatles ": 1968,
    "Yellow Submarine ": 1969,
    "Abbey Road": 1969,
    "Let It Be ": 1970
}


function getYear(albums) {
    var albumOccurrence = {};
    var max = 0;
    var res = [];
    for (var key in albums) {
        albumOccurrence[albums[key]] = albumOccurrence[albums[key]] ? albumOccurrence[albums[key]] + 1 : 1;
        if (albumOccurrence[albums[key]] > max)
            max = albumOccurrence[albums[key]];
    }
    console.log(max, albumOccurence);
    for (var occurrence in albumOccurrence) {
        if (albumOccurrence[occurrence] == max) {
            res.push(occurrence);
        }
    }
    if (res.length == 1) {
        res = res[0];
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(getYear(albums));
```

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Awesome..! This is the solution that I  was trying for. Thanks, @Dinesh K.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new data structure from your starting one, having the year as key, and then as value the array of the albums.

Then you can loop over your new data stracture, and get the max number of albums and the key (year) corresponding to that max:

```js
var x = {
 "Please Please Me": 1963,
 "With the Beatles": 1963,
 "A Hard Day's Night ": 1964, 
 "Beatles for Sale ": 1964, 
 "Twist and Shout ": 1964, 
 "Help ": 1965, 
 "Rubber Soul ": 1965,
 "Revolver": 1966,
 "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band": 1967,
 "Magical Mystery Tour ": 1967, 
 "The Beatles ": 1968, 
 "Yellow Submarine ": 1969 ,
 "Abbey Road": 1969, 
 "Let It Be ": 1970
};
const res = {};
for (let key in x) {
  if (!res[x[key]]){
    res[x[key]] = [];
  }
  res[x[key]].push(key);
}

let max = 0;
let maxKeys = [];
for (let key in res) {
  if (max < res[key].length) {
    max = res[key].length;
    maxKeys = [key];
  }
  else if (max === res[key].length) {
    maxKeys.push(key);
  }
}
maxKeys.forEach(key => {
  console.log('Max year:', key, '\n', 'Albums number', res[key].length, '\n', 'Albums', res[key]);
});
```

Comment: @quirimno Thanks for the solution. This is working great, But the problem here is if in my object I have two/more years have same albums then I need to return an array of two years. Try to change the years of the albums.

Comment: Check for duplicate album number cases .

Comment: @Anji check answer below

Comment: @Anji sorry I didn't get that requirement. Just changed now

Comment: @quirimmo, Now your solution is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects. Each object can have a year, an array of movies and the number of movies. Then on sorting the array will give the object which have highest movies

```js
let data = {
  "Please Please Me": 1963,
  "With the Beatles": 1963,
  "A Hard Day's Night": 1964,
  "Beatles for Sale": 1964,
  "Twist and Shout": 1964,
  "Help": 1965,
  "Rubber Soul": 1965,
  "Revolver": 1966,
  "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band": 1967,
  "Magical Mystery Tour": 1967,
  "The Beatles": 1968,
  "Yellow Submarine": 1969,
  'Abbey Road': 1969,
  "Let It Be": 1970
}

let yearObj = []
// iterating the object and creating an array of objects
for (let keys in data) {
  // check in the array , if there exist an object which have smae year
  let checkIfKeyPresent = yearObj.findIndex(item => {
    return item.year === data[keys]
  })
  // if the year exist then just update movies array and the count
  if (checkIfKeyPresent !== -1) {
    yearObj[checkIfKeyPresent]['movieNo'] += 1;
    yearObj[checkIfKeyPresent]['movies'].push(keys)
  } else {
    // if it does not exist then create a new object with following keys and
    // push it to the main array
    yearObj.push({
      year: data[keys],
      movieNo: 1,
      movies: [keys]
    })
  }
}
let k = yearObj.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.movies.length - a.movies.length
})
console.log(yearObj[0])
```